# Why is Shabbat observed according to the time zone one is in rather than according to the one where the mitzvah of Shabbat was given?

Tags: shabbat

Why is Shabbat observed, Friday night through Saturday day, according to the time zone that one is in rather than the time zone that the mitzvah of Shabbat was given in (the time zone of Mt. Sinai)?

Comment: Hi there namesake! This is an interesting question but it's not quite clear what you mean. Where is "there"? When does G-d say this? If you edit your question to include these elements you'll get better answers :)

Comment: @יהושעק why do we not start Shabbat in the time zone that mount saini (I think that is where g-d told us about this mitzva)

Comment: Why don't the jews in diaspora keep the Shabbat according to the time zone of the land of Israel?

Comment: If you lived 3000 years ago, how could you know when is the sunset of a far location?

Comment: I don't think people quite understood in the Late Iron Age that there are different time zones. The Torah was issued as a practicable legislation in its own time.

Comment: @Deuteronomy more specifically, there were no "time zones" (and no standardized time, and no accurate clocks). Those are all our inventions. They had sunrise, sunset, etc, and they could calculate distances between them *for a specific place* with reasonable accuracy. Being able to calculate times for other places would probably require more knowledge about the size of the Earth, distances, latitude/longitude/elevation than they did then (they had an understanding of these things, but I don't know if it was accurate enough to calculate times for a random place).

Comment: Anyone who knows that the world is round knows that there are time zones. Anyone who looks at the ocean horizon from the top of a tower knows that the world is round, and can make a rough estimate of its size.

Comment: The question seems to ask, Assuming that everyone at the time of the Torah was ignorant, why don't those who accept them as our ultimate guides for life go along with their ignorance? I'm not sure how to make sense out of that.

Comment: https://www.trailnotes.org/SizeOfTheEarth/

Comment: @MichoelR no, "time zones" are our invention. sunrise and sunset don't happen at the same time, but giving any name to a time independent of sunrise/sunset/etc is a recent invention of people and not inherent in the world. In general, measuring time exactly is a recent(ish) invention, and times that are consistent across multiple locations (rather than just one town/city) are even more recent and only necessary once the world became more interconnected.

Comment: @Esther I simply used "time zones" as a shorthand for the notion that sunrise/sunset occur at different times in different places... it is quite obviously, as you point out, a modern construct. As for the rest, agreed.

Comment: @Esther I think you are taking the idea of "time zone" (i.e., the same hour across a wedge 1/24th of the planet), and inserting into the discussion here where it doesn't belong. Here the issue is, Going to a different place on earth where the time of dawn or sunset or chatzos is different, does that affect the halacha or not? I think it is obvious that it should, and that anyone who knew anything 5,000 years of ago would have known that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commandment is given as applying to the seventh of the seven days. Days are defined by sunrise and sunset. Your question seems to assume G-d started a metaphorical clock and said in so many hours it will be Sabbath worldwide. Instead, G-d said the seventh day shall be holy. Wherever you are, after sunset of the sixth day until sunset of the seventh day, it is the Sabbath.